# HttpException: Why doesn't Application_Error in my global.asax catch the "Request Timed Out" exception

Tags: asp.net

When a page times out(Request Timed Out) in my application, the Application_Error sub in my Global.asax is not being fired.  I have custom code in place to redirect an user a custom error page when application errors occur.  Why is the HttpException not being captured?

Comment: Where are you seeing this exception?  Are you sure you're not just seeing a browser error?

Comment: It's shows when the sql request times out.  It's the classic yellow and red ASP.NET exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry I misunderstood.

If you are having a timeout request ASP.NET kills the thread because the runtime will throw a ThreadAbortException which will not be caught be global.asax Application_Error

Comment: No its not being handled in the page.  The web config doesn't have the defaultRedirect value set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's along the lines of what I suspected, just didn't know the exact reason.